# How can I hide the reference links in the TOC, LOF, and LOT globally (shared preamble)?

Tags: hyperref, tocloft

## Question

How can I use `hypersetup{hidelinks}` globally, such that the scope is the TOC, LOF, and LOT *only*?

### Situation

I have many documents that share a common preamble. I am using the `\hyperref` package for linkage and `tocloft` for customization of the ToC, LoF, and LoT. I would like the links in the body to be visible (color change). I would like the ToC, LoF, and LoT to have links, yet I do not want any changes to the formatting (no color change).

```
\usepackage[%
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red,
    hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
```

### Attempt

My attempt makes global changes, because I do not how to insert the `\endgroup`/`\egroup` at the end of the ToC.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\bgroup\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
```

Comment: Just add `\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\oldtableofcontents\addtocontents{toc}{\egroup}}`.

Comment: That does not seem to work :/ Maybe I implemented it wrong.

Comment: Doesn't my answer work for you, or I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: It does indeed! Thanks. I'd still like to know how to implement Werner's comment for the sake of learning.

Comment: @macmadness86 Werner's code works only if you put it inside the document and if `\tableofcontents` is issued at the end of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `\bgroup` in your definition since the change is local to the ToC.

You should issue the following three commands to hide the colors in ToC, LoT and LoF:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}   
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[%
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red,
    hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
\listoffigures
\section{A section}\label{sec}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}\label{table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{A figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}

\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\section{Another section}
A reference to section \ref{sec} and to table \ref{table} and to figure \ref{figure}.
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]